# how to solve buggy scrolling after using removeChild

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, mobile-safari, bookmarklet

So there is this webpage:

```
<body class="" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div> <!-- stuff --> </div>
    <div class="AbCde Zy1XW   ">
        <!-- unwanted crap -->
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to remove
`class="AbCde Zy1XW   "`
and
`style="overflow: hidden;"`
from
`body`
so I used this code:

```
  d=document
  e=d.getElementsByClassName("AbCde Zy1XW   ")[0];
  e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
  document.querySelector('body').removeAttribute('style');
```

It works but the problem is that the scrolling of the webpage is buggy on iOS. You have to zoom in and out before you can scroll normally. But after a while, you can't scroll anymore and need to do the zoom out/zoom in trick again. Any ideas why? Thanks

#### **EDIT:**

Using
`remove();`
also has this same issue...

Comment: No need to remove the whole attribute just change the specific style: `d.body.style.overflow='initial'`. Might need it on the main html node as well `d.documentElement.style.overflow='initial'`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks that works if I input into browser console but if i use it as a bookmarklet, it just replaces the whole webpage with the word "initial"... Why is this so?

Comment: @PatrickEvans The whole code doesn't work now after adding

`return false;`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Did it like this
`javascript:d=document,e=d.getElementsByClassName("RnEpo Yx5HN   ")[0];e.parentNode.removeChild(e);d.body.style.overflow='initial';return false;`

Also tried what you said

`javascript:d=document,e=d.getElementsByClassName("RnEpo Yx5HN   ")[0];e.parentNode.removeChild(e);d.body.style.overflow='initial', return false;`

but doesn't work either...

Comment: Thought the `return false` used to work, guess i was wrong. Ok try wrapping in an iife instead (without return part), eg `javascript:(function(){ ....style.overflow='initial';})()`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks it's working now but if I were to use this bookmarklet on a iPhone, the scrolling is abit buggy, I have to zoom out a bit before I can scroll, otherwise I can't scroll at all... Any ideas why?

Comment: Not sure never really used ios or safari. It might be something the site itself is doing or a quirk of ios/safari. You could try other values for overflow like `visible`, `auto`, or `scroll` but dont know if they would affect the behavior

Comment: @PatrickEvans Tried all 3 of them but the buggy scrolling is still there... Thanks anyways